# Numerical integration of a periodic function result in an increasing function

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, signal-processing

I have a sequence of a samples coming from sampled and processed periodic signals. I need to approximate the integral of these signals.

Using scipy.integrate.cumtrapz which applies the composite trapezoidal rule I obtained the integrated samples, but I have a problem. **One of these integrated functions become a decreasing function**, and I have no idea of what is going on...
This is the simply code I used:

```
test_set_y_int = integrate.cumtrapz(test_set_y) 
y_int = integrate.cumtrapz(y)
```

The plot of the initial signals, the blue one is test_set_y, the red one is y :
[image: initial signals]

The plot of the integrated signals, the blue one is test_set_y_int, the red one is y_int. [image: integrated signals]

Any suggestions about what is happening and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

That's not surprising, as a simpler example may show more clearly: $f(x)=1+\cos x$ is periodic, and $\int^x_0f(x)\,dx=x+\sin x$ is increasing.

Comment: This is true, but why is the blue signal shifted only vertically and it is not decreasing? They have more or less the same waveform, shouldn't they behave in a similar way?

Comment: If it's just $0.01+\cos x$, you can't detect that from the signal itself, because random errors of measurements are larger, but integrating over such a large interval of several hundred units, you'd detect the linear summand $0.01 x$.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for the clarification.